# Trying out Squeel but symbols don't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, squeel

I'm trying the following query

```
  results = Tickets.order("created_at DESC").where({
    (title =~ params[:title]) &
    (name =~ params[:from]) |
    (problem =~ params[:includes]) &
    (problem !~ params[:excludes])
  })
```

but the following error occurs

> > syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
> >                 (problem !~ params[:excludes])})

and for the other lines too

but the squeel doc says to do:

```
Person.where{(name =~ 'Ernie%') & (salary < 50000) | (name =~ 'Joe%') & (salary > 100000)}
```

ps, i've spotted it. first to spot it too gets a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses: one immediately after "where" and one at the very end.